# How to process many form inputs with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, serialization

I am building a admin panel for a distribution company and they requested to have a page where they can add orders for all clients , so i generated a form  which dynamically adds inputs for each product within the system and and for each client a row is created (see [image: picture])

|The problem is , every product/client that is added, will add more and more inputs, i already had to increase max_input_vars, but this can easily reach to thousands , if not tens of thousands of inputs which will slow down the application dramatically , my question is, what is the best approach to process all these inputs, or another approach to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: 1. Don't allow them to add tens of thousands of inputs. That's insane. Give them a reasonable hard limit. 2. I just did something very similar, I just iterate through the product rows and add them to the form data manually, granted mine was just a contact form so a little easier, but the concept is the same.

Comment: the form is created dynamically, from the products table so however many products are added, will be inserted into the form and all products must be displayed so that they can add that product into the order , so i cant make a limit, can you explain why iterating over product rows will help?

Comment: In your "dynamic" table code add logic like: `if( rows * columns > field_limit ) { raise_error }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either reconsider to add an maximum to the amount of input fields which are added per client or create a seperate page for each client on which the input fields are generated.

If you do want to continue you might want to consider extending the `max_execution_time` which defaults to 30 seconds, by adding `ini_set('maximum_execution_time', '60');` to the top of your script.

To process all those rows on the server side. Make your input fields arrays which hold the client name as a key: `<input type="text" name="your_value[client1][column1]" />` and for your next client do `<input type="text" name="your_value[client2][column1]" />` increment the column for each column.

Then on the server side your can perform a foreach loop to get the values.

```
foreach($_POST[your_value] as $client)
{
    foreach($client as $key => $val)
    {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: will this treat each array as one variable in the request?

Comment: You could create a variable for each client. Your serverside array would look like this:
`array(2) { ["client1"]=> array(2) { ["column1"]=> string(6) "value1" ["column2"]=> string(6) "value2" } ["client2"]=> array(2) { ["column1"]=> string(6) "value1" ["column2"]=> string(6) "value2" } }`

Comment: i understand but why would that help the speed, right now all the inputs are named like this [ name="clientId_ProductID"] so i like your approach, because it  a lot cleaner but will that increase the speed or consider each array and its content as one variable

Comment: It wont. As @RickCalder mentioned give your users a hard limit. As tens of thousands of inputs is just insane and will for sure crash your application.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript (or something client side) to only submit the data that has changed.

If the chart is filled with stored data (in a DB I assume) than when an entry is changed you can use an AJAX request to your php script so it saves the changed data to the DB.